# C# Deleting a IIS virtual directory on windows server 2003 gives a COMException

Tags: iis, virtual-directory, comexception

```
  DirectoryEntry oDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(virtualDirMetaPath);
  oDirectoryEntry.DeleteTree();
```

This throws a COMException 0x80005000. Any pointers welcome. Creation of virtual directory is fine. Its only at uninstall I get this error logged in Event Viewver.

Answer (score 0):

How come you're using `DirectoryEntry`, which is purely ActiveDirectory-related class, to manage IIS virtual directories? See [this](http://blogs.officezealot.com/charles/archive/2004/10/26/3191.aspx) for pointers.

Comment: You can use DirectoryEntry Class to manage all settings within IIS.